# Python SumIfs for list of list dates

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary, python-datetime

I have a list of lists composed of dates in excel float format (every minute since July 5, 1996) and an integer value associated with each date like this: `[[datetime,integer]...]`. I need to create a new list composed of all of the dates (no hours or minutes) and the sum of the values for all of the datetimes within that date. In other words, what is the sum of the values for each date when `listolists[x][0] >= math.floor(listolists[x][0])` and `listolists[x][0] < math.floor(listolists[x][0])`. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "the datetimes within that date"?

Comment: I think she wants to sum all of the by-minute values for a given day.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any actual data (just the data structure you used, nested lists), I created some dummy data below to demonstrate how you might do a `SUMIFS`-type of problem in Python.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates_list = []

# just take one month as an example of how to group by day
year = 2015
month = 12

# generate similar data to what you might have
for day in range(1, 32):
    for hour in range(1, 24):
        for minute in range(1, 60):
            dates_list.append([datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute), np.random.randint(20)])

# unpack these nested list pairs so we have all of the dates in 
# one list, and all of the values in the other
# this makes it easier for pandas later
dates, values = zip(*dates_list)

# to eventually group by day, we need to forget about all intra-day data, e.g.
# different hours and minutes. we only care about the data for a given day, 
# not the by-minute observations. So, let's set all of the intra-day values to
# some constant for easier rolling-up of these dates.
new_dates = []

for d in dates:
    new_d = d.replace(hour = 0, minute = 0)
    new_dates.append(new_d)

# throw the new dates and values into a pandas.DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame({'new_dates': new_dates, 'values': values})

# here's the SUMIFS function you're looking for
grouped = df.groupby('new_dates')['values'].sum()
```

Let's see the results:

```
>>> print(grouped.head())
new_dates
2015-12-01    12762
2015-12-02    13292
2015-12-03    12857
2015-12-04    12762
2015-12-05    12561
Name: values, dtype: int64
```

Edit: If you want these new grouped data back in the nested list format, just do this:

```
new_list = [[date, value] for date, value in zip(grouped.index, grouped)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. This is the simplest code I could come up with that doesn't require panda:

```
for row in listolist:
     for k in (0, 1):
         row[k] = math.floor(float(row[k]))
date = {}
for d,v in listolist:
    if d in date:
        date[math.floor(d)].append(v)
    else:
        date[math.floor(d)] = [v]
result = [(d,sum(v)) for d,v in date.items()]
```